# GROUP BY and HAVING in linq

Tags: linq, count, group-by, having

I want to convert this code to linq:

```
select t1.title, COUNT(*)as num 
from t1 INNER join t2 on t2.gId = t1.Id 
group by t1.title, t1.cId 
having t1.cId = 2
```

I tried this below code:

```
from p in db.t1s join r in db.t2s on p.Id equals r.gId 
where p.cId == 2 
group p by p.title into g 
select new{ name = from o in g select o.title, num = g.Count()}
```

But this doesn't return COUNT correctly.

please guide me how can I solve the problem

thanks

Comment: Please give some sample data, expected results and actual results. Also, that definitely isn't your actual code, given that it would be `Count` rather than `count`. We can't tell what *else* isn't accurate...

Comment: In your second query you group by `title` which clearly is different than grouping by `title, cId`.

Comment: And the `having` clause is meant to query aggregated values like sum or count, but you use `having t1.cId = 2`. This should be done in a `where` clause (as your linq query will do, by the way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample data its hard to get it right, but try this snippet

```
from p in db.t1s 
join r in db.t2s on p.Id equals r.gId 
where p.cId == 2 
group p by new {p.title, p.cId} into grouped
select new{ name = grouped.Key.title, num = grouped.Count()}
```

Also, note that this sql:

```
select t1.title, COUNT(*)as num 
from t1 INNER join t2 on t2.gId = t1.Id 
group by t1.title, t1.cId 
having t1.cId = 2
```

Will always return 1 as result of COUNT(*). The reason is that you have filtering t1.cId = 2 and grouping by t1.cId  as second parameter.

Comment: Thanks. It's hard to construct linq without data source having all issues in head. Fixed.